# Bash: how to evaluate results of commands inside double brackets

Tags: bash, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I guess `mytrue` and `myfalse` are considered strings instead of commands:

```
myfalse () {
    return 0
}

mytrue () {
    return 1
}

test-conditional ( ) {
    SHOW="dont-show"
    [[ ${SHOW} == "show" || mytrue ]] && echo "ok" || echo "wrong"
    [[ ${SHOW} == "show" && mytrue ]] && echo "err" || echo "ok"
    [[ ${SHOW} == "show" || myfalse ]] && echo "err" || echo "ok"
    [[ ${SHOW} == "show" && myfalse ]] && echo "err" || echo "ok"
    SHOW="show"
    [[ ${SHOW} == "show" || mytrue ]] && echo "ok" || echo "err"
    [[ ${SHOW} == "show" && mytrue ]] && echo "ok" || echo "err"
    [[ ${SHOW} == "show" || myfalse ]] && echo "ok" || echo "err"
    [[ ${SHOW} == "show" && mytrue ]] && echo "err" || echo "ok"

}

test-conditional
```

So this is showing wrong output:

```
ok
ok
err
ok
ok
ok
ok
err
```

(It should be `ok` everywhere)

How can evaluate commands inside double brackets?

Comment: You don't, just remove the brackets. or only include the `==` comparison inside, i.e `[[ ${SHOW} == "show" ]] || mytrue`

Comment: Also 0 is true in bash.

Answer (score 4):

You have `true` and `false` functions returning opposite return codes and your last condition needs a correction.

You can use:

```
myfalse () {
   return 1
}

mytrue () {
   return 0
}

test-conditional ( ) {
    SHOW="dont-show"
    [[ ${SHOW} == "show" ]] || mytrue && echo "ok" || echo "wrong"
    [[ ${SHOW} == "show" ]] && mytrue && echo "err" || echo "ok"
    [[ ${SHOW} == "show" ]] || myfalse && echo "err" || echo "ok"
    [[ ${SHOW} == "show" ]] && myfalse && echo "err" || echo "ok"
    SHOW="show"
    [[ ${SHOW} == "show" ]] || mytrue && echo "ok" || echo "err"
    [[ ${SHOW} == "show" ]] && mytrue && echo "ok" || echo "err"
    [[ ${SHOW} == "show" ]] || myfalse && echo "ok" || echo "err"
    [[ ${SHOW} == "show" ]] && myfalse && echo "err" || echo "ok"
}

test-conditional
```

Also note how function call is placed outside `[[ ... ]]` otherwise it won't invoke function.

Following rules apply while evaluating these expressions:

1. Condition after `&&` isn't evaluated if first condition fails.
2. Condition after `||` isn't evaluated if first condition succeeds.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain how are those logical expressions evaluated? What are the precedence rules? Are mytrue / myfalse always called? I assume not, because echo is not always called. How does this exactly work?

Comment: These are standard programming logical constructs. 1. Condition after `&&` isn't evaluated if first condition fails. 2. Condition after `||` isn't evaluated if first condition succeeds.

Comment: And `&&` has precendence over `||`? That is: `a && b || c` means `(a && b) || c`, and `a || b && c` means `a || (b && c)`? It is confusing because the && operators in bash seem to do slightly different things inside and outside brackets (probably not the case when using double brackets)

Comment: This does not answer what the question title is asking: "inside double brackets".

Comment: @delavnog: `a && b || c` means evaluate `b` if `a` succeeds and evaluate `c` if `a` fails. These conditions will be evaluated from left to right so `[[ ${SHOW} == "show" ]] && myfalse && echo "err" || echo "ok"` is equivalent of `{ [[ ${SHOW} == "show" ]] && myfalse; } && echo "err" || echo "ok"`

Answer (score 1):

Inside a bash `[[…]]` (and inside the older `[…]` in most shells) what matters is if the value tested has some characters or not:

```
$ [[ somevalue ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
```

If the value tested if empty, the test fails:

```
$ [[ "" ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
no
```

That is also true for variables:

```
$ somevalue="a false string"
$ [[ $somevalue ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
yes

$ somevalue=""
$ [[ $somevalue ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
no
```

So, `[[…]]` is limited to testing strings not "exit codes".
Your functions define "exit codes" not strings.
You may

1. define the values of `mytrue` and `myfalse` to be variables that represent those values:

   ```
   mytrue=A_True_Value
   myfalse=""
   ```

   And use them:

   ```
   $ show="dont-show"
   $ [[ ${SHOW} == "show" || $mytrue ]] && echo "ok" || echo "wrong"
   ok

   $ [[ ${SHOW} == "show" || $myfalse ]] && echo "ok" || echo "wrong"
   wrong
   ```
2. Or, actually test exit codes outside a `[[…]]` idiom:

   ```
   $ mytrue(){ return 0; }
   $ if mytrue; then echo "ok"; else echo "wrong"; fi
   ok

   $ mytrue && echo "ok" || echo "wrong"
   ok
   ```
3. One (more complex) alternative is to make the functions emit a value and call the execution of the code in the functions from the `[[…]]` idiom:

   ```
   $ mytrue(){ echo "A_True_Value"; }
   $ myfalse(){ echo ""; }
   $ show="dont-show"
   $ [[ ${SHOW} == "show" || $(mytrue) ]] && echo "ok" || echo "wrong"
   ok
   ```

## KISS

But (probably) the simplest of solutions is the best solution:

```
myfalse=""
mytrue="true"

test-conditional () {
    show="dont-show"
    [[ ${show} == "show" || $mytrue  ]] && echo "ok"  || echo "wrong"
    [[ ${show} == "show" && $mytrue  ]] && echo "err" || echo "ok"
    [[ ${show} == "show" || $myfalse ]] && echo "err" || echo "ok"
    [[ ${show} == "show" && $myfalse ]] && echo "err" || echo "ok"
    show="show"
    [[ ${show} == "show" || $mytrue  ]] && echo "ok"  || echo "err"
    [[ ${show} == "show" && $mytrue  ]] && echo "ok"  || echo "err"
    [[ ${show} == "show" || $myfalse ]] && echo "ok"  || echo "err"
    [[ ${show} == "show" && $myfalse ]] && echo "err" || echo "ok"
}

test-conditional
```

Comment: actually, mytrue and myfalse are not constants: I am using that to simulate a `check` function which can return 1 for false and 0 for true (I was using the wrong return values in my original question). That said, I like the simplicity of the last section in your reply: how can I do that, making sure that: 1) the `check` function is called 2) the return value is checked, not the emitted text

Comment: Inside a [[…]] you can only either test some text (variable) or the output of a command (function/alias). If you set the requirement of `not the emitted text` part, then you are rejecting the "output of a command", then, the only way to make a test is using a variable. That's the solution I wrote. (Contd....)

Comment: The only other alternative is to make the tests outside a [[…]]. That is what has been provided by other users by building an "AND - OR" compound command. I can not figure a way to execute code and test for a value (that is not an "emited text"), not even with arithmetic expansions. Seems to me that your set of requirements can all be met at the same time. (Contd.)

Comment: You can define a function that test anything you want and change a variable `mytestedvalue` to either some true value or empty. Execute the function and then the variable could be tested with the code I provided (again, inside `[[…]]`). Or make the test for the exit value outside the `[[…]]`. Something like `if mytestfunction; then … fi`. Of course, mytestfunction could very well be callled `mytrue`.